# Delaying a jquery script until everything else has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a jquery script which I need to run only once everything else on the page, including some other javascripts (over which I have no control) have finished doing their thing.

I though perhaps there was an alternative to $(document).ready but I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that because of a peculiar mixture of javascript frameworks that I needed to initiate the script using an event listener provide by one of the other frameworks.

Comment: Happy that you found a solution but your answer is not the useful for others without more details...

Answer (score 235):

You can have `$(document).ready()` multiple times in a page. The code gets run in the sequence in which it appears.

You can use the `$(window).load()` event for your code since this happens after the page is fully loaded and all the code in the various `$(document).ready()` handlers have finished running.

```
$(window).load(function(){
  //your code here
});
```

Comment: can I import external scripts using this method?

Comment: Sure, if you are already doing this inside $(document).ready(), this will be no different.

Comment: This answer was useful to me because I didn't realise that jquery code gets run in sequence

Comment: @JoseBasilio without knowing if jQuery has loaded `$(document).ready` will produce `$ is undefined` right!!

Comment: Thank you SO much! This fixed my .height() issue where it wasn't getting the correct height because the page (apparently) wasn't loaded yet.

Comment: Rails users only:
 When using with turbolinks, it sometimes is not sufficient.

Comment: Just FYI: This does NOT wait for fonts to load.  There's really no good way of doing that as of yet.

Comment: Very useful when appending new nodes to dynamically created elements.

Comment: In JQuery 3.0, you should use the syntax `$(window).on('load', function() {
});` since $(window).load() is deprecated.

Answer (score 21):

This code block solve my problem,

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).bind("load", function () {
    // Code here
  });
</script>
```

Comment: How can you run a jQuery function to see if jQuery is already loaded? This will work only when jQuery has loaded prior to the checking.

Comment: Great, it works!

Comment: This one absolutely works for me! Thank you a million

Answer (score 13):

Multiple `$(document).ready()` will fire in order top down on the page.  The last `$(document).ready()` will fire last on the page.  Inside the last `$(document).ready()`, you can trigger a new custom event to fire after all the others..

Wrap your code in an event handler for the new custom event.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    $(document).on("my-event-afterLastDocumentReady", function () {
        // Fires LAST
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Fires FIRST
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Fires SECOND
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Fires THIRD
    });
</script>
<body>
... other code, scripts, etc....
</body>
</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Fires FOURTH
        // This event will fire after all the other $(document).ready() functions have completed.
        // Usefull when your script is at the top of the page, but you need it run last
        $(document).trigger("my-event-afterLastDocumentReady");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://www.nabble.com/Loading-jQuery-UI-dialogs-from-GreaseMonkey--td19897312s27240.html):

```
// Add jQuery 
var GM_JQ = document.createElement('script'); 
GM_JQ.src = 'http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js';
GM_JQ.type = 'text/javascript'; 
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(GM_JQ); 

// Check if jQuery's loaded 
function GM_wait() 
{ 
    if(typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') 
    { 
        window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery; 
        letsJQuery(); 
    } 
} 

GM_wait(); 

// All your GM code must be inside this function 
function letsJQuery() 
{
    // Do your jQuery stuff in here    
}
```

This will wait until jQuery is loaded to use it, but you can use the same concept, setting variables in your other scripts (or checking them if they're not your script) to wait until they're loaded to use them.

For example, on my site, I use this for asynchronous JS loading and waiting until they're finished before doing anything with them using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"> 
    function js(url){
        s = document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
    }       

    js("/js/jquery-ui.js");
    js("/js/jrails.js");
    js("/js/jquery.jgrowl-min.js");
    js("/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js");
    js("/js/jquery.corner-min.js");
    js("/js/jquery.cookie-min.js");
    js("/js/application-min.js");

    function JS_wait() {
        if (typeof $.cookie == 'undefined' || // set in jquery.cookie-min.js
            typeof getLastViewedAnchor == 'undefined' || // set in application-min.js
            typeof getLastViewedArchive == 'undefined' || // set in application-min.js 
            typeof getAntiSpamValue == 'undefined') // set in application-min.js
        { 
            window.setTimeout(JS_wait, 100); 
        }
        else 
        { 
            JS_ready(); 
        }
    }

    function JS_ready() {
        // snipped
    };

    $(document).ready(JS_wait);
</script>
```

Comment: This will only wait until jQuery is loaded and disregard other aspects of the page. It's nothing more than a hack for older versions of greasemonkey that don't support the @require directive.

Comment: I've added my code as an example of how I used the same concept with jQuery to wait until other code has loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried loading all the initialization functions using the `$().ready`, running the jQuery function you wanted last?

Perhaps you can use `setTimeout()` on the `$().ready` function you wanted to run, calling the functionality you wanted to load.

Or, use `setInterval()` and have the interval check to see if all the other load functions have completed (store the status in a boolean variable).  When conditions are met, you could cancel the interval and run the load function.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. Are you suggesting I import all the scripts through a jquery script and just put my script last? If so what would that look like (I'm a designer by trade, so don't use big words :))

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    callLoadFunction1();
    callLoadFunction2();
    calljQueryLoadFunction();
});

Comment: the other scripts are all external files so i'm not sure this would work would it?

Comment: @chrism: See my second example. It waits until variables are set indicating the other external JS files have loaded before it does anything. You just put the code you want to run last in my JS_ready() method. It does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Just use ```$(window).load(function(){...})```

Answer (score 0):

The following script ensures that `my_finalFunction` runs after your page has been fully loaded with images, stylesheets and external content:

```
<script>

    document.addEventListener("load", my_finalFunction, false);

    function my_finalFunction(e) {
        /* things to do after all has been loaded */
    }

</script>
```

A good explanation is provided by kirupa on running your code at the right time, see https://www.kirupa.com/html5/running_your_code_at_the_right_time.htm.