# Print via javascript in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, printing

I've looked around here and saw wonderful solutions how to print the content of a div using javascript by instantiating a new window and porting markup there.
My problem with that solution in SharePoint is that SP.*.js libraries load asynchronously and it freezes the print dialog screen or the browser itself.
Anybody was able to workaround this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sharepoint you can use `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` to wait until SP.js loaded to make sure nothing freezes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function printPage(){
  }
  window.onload = function(){ ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(printPage, "sp.js"); };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know SharePoint specifically, so I can't provide a specific example. However, it sounds like you are thinking of a technique like the one outlined on this [other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1687435/1002041).

Notice this is all one block of code that will execute sequentially. So we open a window, set the markup and print right away. No waiting around between those steps.

I would suggest that you don't call print at that point, but rather open the window, set the markup AND inject some more javascript in the new window markup. This new injected javascript will be where the actual printing takes places.

That injected script should have some logic to wait until certain script resources have finished loading after which it calls `window.print()`. Apparently `window.onload` doesn't fire until after all resources have finished loading. ([onload doesn't fire until all content is either loaded or has failed to load](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum91/5301.htm)). Here's a [jquery example on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1012156/1002041). Also scripts are executed in the order the appear in the markup. So if your injected print window javascript is last, every other script above it must already be done. (So anything SharePoint injects in the markup should already have been executed).

For bonus points, if everything is going well, you could inject a 'loading mask' over the new print window and then hide the mask just before your javascript does its `window.print()`.

Answer (score 1):

The code given below will work with sharepoint, ASPX pages and with any browser. I tested the code with Sharepoint 2010 Visual webparts, and it works like a charm.

Place this Javascript code inside your webpart ASCX file

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function printPartOfPage(elementId) {
        var printContent = document.getElementById(elementId);
        var windowUrl = '';
        var uniqueName = new Date();
        var windowName = 'Print' ;
        var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'left=-20,top=-20,width=0,height=0');
        printWindow.document.write('<HTML><Head><Title></Title>');
        printWindow.document.write('</Head><Body style="margin-left:50px;margin-top:50px;font-size:10pt;">');
        printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
        printWindow.document.write('</Body></HTML>');
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.focus();
        printWindow.print();
        printWindow.close();
    }

</script>
```

& Update the print button ClientClick Event with

```
   <img alt="" src="~/_layouts/images/WebpartCollection/Printer-30X30.jpg" 
onclick="JavaScript:printPartOfPage('YourDivClientID');" />
```

I hope this will help you out.

Comment: the issue that i have is that i must bring over the header information from the printing page into the print window which then executes SP client side libraries and this approach does not work all that well.  FF and IE both freeze until the new tab is loaded.  The loading process waits for SP javascript libraries.