# on page redirect, Angular directive's event listener misses jQuery event trigger

Tags: jquery, angularjs, events, redirect, directive

---

TL;DR

I need an Angular linking function to occur before a jQuery click event that is triggered on page redirect.

---

I have an Angular directive that waits for a jQuery click event in its linking function:

```
// something like this
link: function(scope) {

    angular.element('#parent-selector').on('click', '#buttonId') {

        // force digest since looking outside of Angular
        scope.$apply(function() {

            // do some stuff that looks outside of Angular

        });
    }

}
```

My goal is to make that stuff happen.  When I click the button, it does happen, and it makes me happy.  I can click it again and again and again, and the stuff happens; I can reload the page and then click the button, and stuff still happens, and I am sufficiently satisfied.

Well, I also have a different button in a different view with a different URL than where the one that triggers the click event lives.  When this button is clicked, it redirects to the view with the Angular directive and the jQuery click event.  Upon redirect, it calls the jQuery click event to trigger the functionality that I so desire, but to no avail.  Now I am sad.

```
// something along these lines
$('#buttonId').trigger('click');
```

Using 'debugger' and looking in Chrome dev tools I have been able to ascertain the following:

1. When it works, and I am happy, it is because the Angular directive's linking function loads first.  This makes sense, since the directive can set up the listener before the event triggers.
2. When it doesn't work, and I am sad, it is because the Angular directive's linking function loads after the jQuery click event triggers.  Note that it is still listening for the event, as any subsequent clicks of the button do trigger the stuff, as expected.

But that first trigger, the forced click on page redirect, is occurring before the linking function has an opportunity to listen for it.

Any thoughts, suggestions, questions?  I know that this is a bit vague, and I apologize for that.  I would be happy to provide more details.  The key is to note that everything is working, with the exception of the timing of events.  I fully expect the stuff to happen as I desire if only, after the redirect, the Angular linking function can load before the click trigger.

Comment: I tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012140/delaying-a-jquery-script-until-everything-else-has-loaded) which helped the timing out on page reload (angular directive first, click trigger second) but it still goes in the wrong order when redirected to this view.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by using Angular to look for the page redirect, which I accomplished by passing $window into the directive as a dependency.

```
// on redirect...
if ($window.location.hash == '#some-hash') {
    // do stuff that I want to get done
}
```

Note that this doesn't really solve the issue.  I would consider it a hack to get the functionality I want to work.

But the question still remains: why does the Angular directive's link function happen after the jQuery trigger only on page redirect, rather than before like on page reload (even when I make jQuery wait for the document to be ready or the window to load)?