# jQuery loading order in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, load-order

I have a jQuery script that reads img height and adds style tag to head tag.

jQuery

```
var img = document.getElementById('logomini');  
height = img.clientHeight;

$(function (){
    $("<style type='text/css' id='style1'>#menu ul { line-height: "+ height +"px }</style>").appendTo("head");
});
```

The problem: sometimes the script is working properly and sometimes it's not. When I'm refreshing my website (Wordpress) the line-height is 80px or 0px. I think it's a problem with script loading. When script is loading faster than img it showing 0px. But it's only my guess... The script tag is right before `</body>` tag.

[my demo page](http://s592293456.websitehome.co.uk/demos/)

Any ideas?

Comment: You are setting the height variable before the image, you're getting the height from, is loaded. You should be defining the variables within the document ready function.

Comment: well, still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be sure the image is fully loaded first, then use this code:

```
/* In WordPress, $ may be used for other libraries, so use this safer "document ready" method */
jQuery(function($) {
    /* wait until everything in the window has loaded */
    $(window).load(function() {
        var img = document.getElementById('logomini');  
        height = img.clientHeight;
        // The above two lines could be simplified like so:  
        var height = $('#logomini').height();
        $("<style type='text/css' id='style1'>#menu ul { line-height: "+ height +"px }</style>").appendTo("head");
    });
});
```

Also see this answer: [Delaying a jquery script until everything else has loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012140/delaying-a-jquery-script-until-everything-else-has-loaded)

Comment: Sorry :) well nothing changed. Still, sometimes is working properly, sometimes it's not.