# Sometimes I need to refresh my page to make my jQuery script at footer work

Tags: jquery, css

I have a fixed header, because it is fixed it *eats* some of the page, so I need to add a `margin-top` to the `first-page-content`. I thought about using a jQuery script that checks the `header`'s rendered `height` and add that as the `margin-top` to the `first-page-content`. It works, though at times I need to refresh the page, and that's quite troublesome for users.

Script (at the footer):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // This function is activated after the document is loaded
  $('.first-page-content').css('margin-top', $('#header').height()); // Sets the margin-top of the first-page-content as the height of the header
});
```

[In case you need the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2)

Edit: When it doesn't work the header *eats* some of the `.first-page-content`, because there is no `margin-top`.

Comment: First off, if the script is in the footer, you don't need the document ready.  Secondly, you didn't state "why" you have to refresh.  What the actual problem is.

Comment: @Taplar, thanks, I'll remove the `$(document).ready()` :]

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
  $('.first-page-content').css('margin-top', $('#header').height()); // Sets the margin-top of the first-page-content as the height of the header
});
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012140/delaying-a-jquery-script-until-everything-else-has-loaded)

Answer (score 0):

Read about:

```
setInterval(my_function,500);
```

Then Your function that remove/create margin will be refreshed always after 0.5 seconds.